# Auto Growth in % ? What exactly it does?

Tags: sql-server-2014, transaction-log, auto-growth

I am new to SQL DBA Administration. Please help me understand the below scenario.

As it is really confusing. Please help.

What does it mean keeping the Auto Growth in Percentage.

**For example:**

My SQLLOG Drive (E:) is 300 GB in total.

If I keep 10 % Auto Growth will it take 10% of 300 GB which is 30 GB.

Every time the transaction file needs space it occupies 30 GB of total 300 GB ?

What does 10% Auto Growth mean actually ?

To which file this 10% Auto Growth applies and how space is utilized based on this Auto Growth 10 % ?

Please help me understand this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward concept - have you tried reading some of the [top search result](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/) 
 articles on it? They explain it well.

Comment: Thank you @JohnM  for the response . the link was so clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10% autogrowth means that your file will grow by 10% of the file's current size.

Let's say you log file is currently 10GB, and set for 10% autogrowth. The first time it grows, it will grow by 10% of 10GB, or 1GB, becoming an 11GB file. The second tie it grows, it'll grow by 10% of 11GB, or 1.1GB, becoming a 12.1 GB file. The next time it grows, it'll grow by 10% of 12.1 GB, or 1.21 GB, becoming a 13.31 GB file. And so on.